# Netlogo Diffusion Confusion

Tags: netlogo

I've been playing around with the diffuse keyword.

Consider the following 3x3 world where there's 3 chemical gradients at the top left corner and no chemical elsewhere. Also, there's no wrap on the edges.

```
[3  0  0 ]
[0  0  0 ]
[0  0  0 ]
```

If I have a diffusion rate of .5, I would expect that `3 (gradient) * .5 (diffusion rate) / 3 (#neighbors) = .5`of the gradient would be given to its 3 neighbors. I would also expect that the original patch has 1.5 units remaining.

However, when I run the diffuse code, it seems that `3 (gradient) * .5 (diffusion rate) / 8 (#neighbors) = .1875` of the gradient is being set to the 3 neighbors. The original patch then has 2.4375 remaining units which isn't .5 of the original gradient. What's going on here? Is this an error or is my understanding incorrect?

See below:

```
patches-own [value]
to setup
  cp
  ask patch 0 2 [ set value 3]
  diffuse value .5
  ask patch 1 1 [ show value]
end

observer: show [value] of patches 
observer: [0.1875 0.1875 0 2.4375 0 0 0 0.1875 0]
observer> ask patch 0 2 [ show count neighbors]
(patch 0 2): 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick edit to your code is if you want the top left patch to have a value of 3, you need to ask patch 0 2. You're currently asking the bottom right patch.

Now, your issue is coming from the fact that when you diffuse, it tried to give 1.5 value away spread out over 8 patches, giving each neighboring patch 0.1875. Since your starting patch is in a corner is is only able to spread out across 3 patches and only gives away  0.5625 (3*.1825).

This leaves the original patch with 2.4375.

Note you do get your expected result if you allow the world to wrap around.

Comment: This would mean that the diffusion-rate is more of an attempted diffusion, rather than the actual diffusion amount. Unfortunately, I need to implement my own diffusion because I'm modeling smoke through a building (smoke can't go through walls). I was just validating my model with the built-in diffusion. Also, "If a patch has fewer than eight neighbors, each neighbor still gets an eighth share; the patch keeps any leftover shares." ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#diffuse This just seems weird to me. Does anyone know the logic behind this design decision?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding simple diffusion here, but maybe diffuse is set up like passive diffusion, where the "particles" move about randomly and diffuse through the "walls" to the (potentially eight) surrounding patches- that would explain the "attempted diffusion", as you have essentially set the rate at which your variable can diffuse through a given wall. Something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/Kzko5) but with eight sides? Obviously I'm just spitballing here, but now I'm curious.

Comment: if you have the same fire in two locations - one with walls and one without - what actually happens? NetLogo assumes that if it can't escape, it stays. I'm not sure that this is a bad assumption because the smoke (presumably) tries to go in all directions. That is, if it is blocked to the north, it doesn't turn round and go to the south, it just stays pushed up against the north wall. Of course, smoke may be special because of pressure differentials.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. @Luke I was trying to duplicate the built-in diffuse method (not necessarily on the particle level). I do like Jen's response. I guess there are different needs for different applications.

Comment: @mattsap yes I agree, JenB's explanation makes sense. Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that as something you should do, more trying to illustrate what I was saying (that the flow rate seems to be consistent regardless of how many surfaces/sides allow diffusion).

Comment: see also "Diffuse Off Edges Example", in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library